# Schedule a windows service to run every two hours

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduling

I have created the Window Service VS2010, Now i want to Schedule that service to run after every 2Hour. For this what is the code..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - you have a windows service or a web service? Do you need to set up a timer inside your windows service or do you need some mechanism to invoke a web service call?

Comment: I need to set up a timer inside your windows service

Comment: @cHao: Yup, using the functionality provided by OS *should* be the default. Alas, old versions of TS were annoying and somewhat quirky(before cca XP SP1, IIRC), so people still disable TS, even though it's no longer a good idea. So code for Windows can't reliably deppend on TS actually working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the RegisterWaitForSingleObject method in the ThreadPool class.

Your service code should look something like this (stolen heavily from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2008/12/18/periodic-execution-in-net.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject.aspx)) :

```
private ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private RegisteredWaitHandle handle;

public void OnStart()
{
    resetEvent.Reset();
    handle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(resetEvent, callBack, null, 7200000, false);
}

public void OnStop()
{
    reset.Set();
}

private void callBack(object state, bool timeout)
{
    if (timeout)
    {
        //Do Stuff Here
    }
    else
    {
        handle.Unregister(null);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Debug or Release folder, you will have an .exe version of the file.

Use Task scheduler to run it whenever you want to.

On Windows XP and Server 2003 you can access this from the Start Menu and clicking on Settings and then Control Panel to Scheduled Tasks

The above will constantly utilize your resources. For intermittent usage  PS Service can do the job:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx